# CSS: IE8 still can't render CSS correctly. Is there any hack?

Tags: css

I use this piece of CSS code for fieldset in my ASP.net

```
.important 
{
    border:1px solid #33CC00;
    padding:8px 10px 7px 20px;
}

.important 
{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.important legend 
{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
    -x-system-font:none;
    background:#F3FFF3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:1px solid #33CC00;
    color:#33AA00;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-size-adjust:none;
    font-stretch:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:normal;
    padding:1px 15px;
}
```

It look fine on FireFox but it look like crap on IE7 and IE8. I'm not sure how i can fix this on IE. Does anyone know any website dealing with CSS hack in IE or should i just give up because life is too short to waste on cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

-moz-border-radius- is a [Mozilla specific selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius) which IE will ignore. [border-radius](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-radius) is the equivalent CSS3 selector, but IE almost certainly won't support it (Firefox 3 does, but I seem to remember there are problems with either the standard or the [implementation](http://virtuelvis.com/download/218/border-radius.html))

Comment: FYI - IE actually renders a rounded edge for Fieldset by default